# MS Word VBA IgnoreSpace and IgnorePunct

Tags: python-3.x, vba, ms-word

I am trying to automate finding and replacing two-word phrase in some Word files by using Python.

I can find and replace whatever I want in Word by using Python, there is no problem about python and Word integration. The problem is that there is always different number of white spaces between these two words which I want to replace with single whitespace or '-'. I am trying to use 'IgnoreSpace' and 'IgnorePunct' arguments to come over this problem but they do not give any response as they are doing in the Word file when I try to do it manually. Here is my function to do this: wd_object is a VBA Range object

```
def find_and_replace(wd_object, find_text, replace_with, replace, wrap , 
                 forward, xformat, match_case, match_whole_word, 
                 match_wildcards, match_sounds_like, match_all_word_forms,
                 ignore_white_space, ignore_punct):
try:
    return wd_object.Find.Execute2007(FindText = find_text, ReplaceWith = replace_with,
                                      Replace = replace, Wrap = wrap, Forward = forward,
                                      Format = xformat, MatchCase = match_case,
                                      MatchWholeWord = match_whole_word,
                                      MatchWildcards = match_wildcards,
                                      MatchSoundsLike = match_sounds_like,
                                      MatchAllWordForms = match_all_word_forms,
                                      IgnoreSpace = ignore_white_space,
                                      IgnorePunct = ignore_punct)
```

Could you please tell me why this is not working?

Comment: have you tried with `wildcards`? [here you find some syntax tips](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, you can make it work that way, but I still wonder why I can not make it work through IgnoreSpaces and IgnorePunct  in Word 2010 VBA.